# What differential equations do these solutions belong to?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the differential equation whose solution is given by $y=Ae^{2x}+Be^{-2x}$ and $y=c(x-c)^2$ where $c$ is a constant.

The first one is easy. It is $y’’-4y=0$ but I’m having trouble with the second one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, we have to eliminate $c$ from $y$ and $y'$.

If $y=c(x-c)^2$ then $y'=2c(x-c)$. Then $4c=y'^2/y$, so
$$y=\frac{y'^2}{4y}\left(x-\frac{y'^2}{4y}\right)^2$$
etc.

Comment: So what is the differential equation?

Comment: The one I wrote above.....

Answer (score 1):

From 
$$
y = c(x-c)^2, \tag{0}
$$
upon differentiating w.r.t. $x$, we obtain
$$
y^\prime = 2c(x-c). \tag{1}
$$
So if $c > 0$, then we get
$$
y^\prime  = 2\sqrt{c} \sqrt{c} (x-c) = 2\sqrt{c} \sqrt{y}.
$$
Thus we have
$$
\sqrt{c} = \frac{y^\prime}{2 \sqrt{y} }, 
$$
and so
$$
c = \frac{ \left( y^\prime \right)^2 }{ 4 y }, \tag{2}
$$
which when substituted in (0) above yields 
$$
y = \frac{ \left( y^\prime \right)^2 }{ 4 y } \left( x - \frac{ \left( y^\prime \right)^2 }{ 4 y } \right)^2.
$$

On the other hand, for $c < 0$ in (1) above, we get 
$$
y^\prime = -2(-c) (x-c) = -2 \sqrt{-c} \sqrt{-c} (x-c) = -2 \sqrt{-c} \sqrt{ - y},
$$
which implies
$$
\sqrt{-c} = \frac{y^\prime}{-2 \sqrt{ -y} },
$$
and hence
$$
-c = \frac{ \left( y^\prime \right) }{ 4 (-y) },
$$
which implies 
$$
c = \frac{ \left( y^\prime \right) }{ 4 y },
$$
which is the same as in (2) above.